# How is one album different from another (with same title and by same artist) in Google Play Music shop?

Tags: google-play-store, google-play-music

I'm looking at the album "Dig Your Own Hole" by Chemical Brothers. In fact, I'm looking at two of them. Is there any significant difference between the two? Are they not duplicates? One is obviously cheaper than the other, but they both contain 11 tracks. I see that one is copyrighted by Astralwerks (1997) and the other by Virgin records (2003). So I take it one of them is a re-issue of the original album then?

[image: a]
© Astralwerks:
https://play.google.com/store/music/album/The_Chemical_Brothers_Dig_Your_Own_Hole?id=B4nqr5yopajig6ftrye7hhqczim

[image: b]
© Virgin records:
https://play.google.com/store/music/album/The_Chemical_Brothers_Dig_Your_Own_Hole?id=B36m3muf76m7bdgjo46sfjlbole

But it's not a physical thing! So what does a re-issue really mean, in the new world of digital downloads? Is the "newer" album re-mastered? It doesn't say so in the title. Are we expected to assume it's re-mastered? I know that streaming services (Spotify and Google Play Music All Access alike) often carry "limited" or "delux" or "remastered" albums (but they usually state so in the title).

Is the same source file or master record used for digitally transferring the audio tracks to Google's catalog in both of these cases? What am I really looking at when I encounter albums that appear to be identical? Why should I choose one over the other? The price aside; they can even be priced the same.

Comment: I guess the only difference is that the supposedly "remastered" 2003 edition actually contains 3 seconds of audio less!... than the original. LOL

Comment: Please stick to the question and the information needed for someone to answer it. Leave the editorializing to your own site.

Comment: Yeah, you are probably right. My mind wandered off there for a moment. It's better this way. I will take the discussion somewhere else if need be. But why be a bore and tell everything? Let everyone discover the truth for themselves. Thanks for setting me straight! I mean it.

Answer (score 1):

There are no differences in the songs. The difference in price is because the albums are from different music labels.

Comment: I see. But what's the significance of that? They are all part of Universal music group now. What difference does it make for sound quality? Does each label have it's own master copy which they encode into MP3 and send off to Google's catalog? How does that work? Or do they just take one and the same master copy and publish it under two different label names and stick a different price tag on it? To me these two albums sound the same. They both use lossy MP3 encoding. Only difference is the price, year, label, and +/- three seconds duration (insignificant).